# Excel - If statement plus concatenation

Tags: excel, if-statement

Let's say I have a cell A1 and, if that cell is blank, I want to print nothing in another cell. But if A1 has something in it, I want to add "Notes:" plus the contents of A1. I feel like I'm close, but it's not quite working:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), "" , "Notes: ",A1)
```

Comment: `=IF(A1="","","Notes: " & A1)`

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you so much!